# Is there an npm package or an express built-in function to import csv data to mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have an application that takes a zip file from an SFTP site, decompresses the zip and saves the unzipped csv file to a folder in my workspace. Currently, I've been manually importing the data into the mongodb, but was looking for a solution to do this automatically once the file is available.

Comment: there is ones for csv, and onces for mogno , you should be able to read csv and put data to mongo, why not do that ?

Comment: There is one to convert it to JSON, and you need to use your queries to push the JSON after conversion.

Answer (score 1):

There is a handy library that i've used to handle reading csv's. It's called [csvtojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson). You could use csvtojson to read the file and convert it to a jsonobject and then insert object into mongodb. See example below.

```
const csvFilePath='<path to csv file>'
const csv=require('csvtojson')

 csv().fromFile(csvFile)
    .subscribe((json)=>{
     return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        // Format and insert into Mongo collection here
     })
    }).on('done',(error)=>{
      //wrap things up here.
    })
```

Comment: This library is great. When it comes to saving the json data to mongodb in the Promise, how do you import that? My db name is orders and my collection name is also orders.

Comment: I would suggest reading the links i'm providing for connecting to mongo and inserting new records. https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-nodejs-mongodb--how-to-get-connected-to-your-database  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertOne/